# VBScript batch html to Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, copy, html

I am looking for a solution to the following VB to batch .html files/url. I want to save the .html files to be opened in Microsoft Word.

This is the code I am working with, but I need it to work for multiple .html files:

```
Option Explicit
'Just change these two lines
Const HTMLFileIn="http://www.example.com"   
Const DocFileOut="H:\Word"

Dim MyWord,oIE
Set MyWord=CreateObject("Word.Document") 
Set oIE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate HTMLFileIn
Attend
oIE.document.body.createTextRange.execCommand("Copy")
Attend
MyWord.Content.Paste
MyWord.SaveAs DocFileOut
MyWord.Close
oIE.Quit
Set oIE=Nothing
Set MyWord=Nothing 
MsgBox HTMLFileIn & " is now saved as " & DocFileOut

Sub Attend
    Wscript.Sleep 500
    While oIE.busy
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Wend
    While oIE.Document.readyState <> "complete"
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the links stored? How will the code decide what to name the new word file?

Comment: Links are from my web site, I have a 1000 pages to convert into word, can the input be centralized into one word file instead of multiple files?

Comment: That is understandable but where are the links saved. The code is supposed to loop through something to retrieve those links... for example a text file or a word file? Also how do you plan to name the new word files?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve.  It seems odd to copy webpage content to MS Word.  What do you intend to do with the data?  IE can save to other formats natively.

Comment: The links are stored in a txt file, concerning the word file naming it would be: sitename.doc

Comment: Also not an expert in VB

Comment: There is a special place in hell for those folks that do not indent their code. ;)

Comment: I want to use this for a site content migration, writers want .doc files for rewrite. Trying to simplify their work instead of copying and pasting from website.

Comment: Do you want to stick with vbscript or vba word will do?

Comment: Not fussy at all, vba is fine.

Comment: And you want all in 1 word file?

Comment: Perhaps try a different approach if this isn't working? Since you own the website content, that implies you have access to the files. So why are you retrieving the files from the web when you could do so locally? If you still want to pull from the internet, have you considered using unix commands like curl/wget? Even on a windows box you can download a decent enough unix terminal.

Comment: I don't have access to the back end unfortunately, and never tried unix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
'~~> Replace this with the text file which has the links
Const hLinksFile As String = "C:\Temp\MyLinks.txt"

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ie As Object

    '~~> Open text file in one go
    Open hLinksFile For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True

    Set XML = CreateObject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp.6.0")

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        ie.Navigate "about:blank"

        With XML
            .Open "get", strData(i), False
            .send
            ie.Document.body.InnerHTML = .responsetext
        End With

        Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        ie.Document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"

        Selection.Paste

        '~~> Move to the end for the next pasting
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.TypeParagraph: Selection.TypeParagraph

        Doevents
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, will give it a try.

Comment: I get a Run-time error: '-2147417848 (80010108) Automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients. The debugger highlighted the following: ie.Document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"

Comment: What changes did you make in the code? Did you try to quit `ie` inside the loop?

Comment: I just changed the location for the txt file